# Request time out when hitting api using URL Sessions

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I have created a function for Hitting API Methods and I use it entire project. This function was working perfect but now when I am using this function maximum times request time takes more time and I get request time out(Only when I am connected to wifi only). I am not sure it is backend issue or my code.

```
// MARK: Calling Web services
class func callWebServices(url: String, methodName: String, parameters: String, showLoader: Bool, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    var url_param = url
    if showLoader {
        KVNProgress.show()
    }
    if(methodName == "GET" && parameters != "") {
        url_param = url_param + "?" + parameters
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url_param)!)
    request.httpMethod = methodName

    if(methodName == "POST" && parameters != "") {
        let postString = parameters
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error = \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        if let httpsStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpsStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("Status Code should be 200, but it is \(httpsStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }
        do {
            let dictData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Json Result :\(dictData)")
                KVNProgress.dismiss()
                completion(dictData)
            }
        } catch {
            KVNProgress.dismiss()
            print("error is : \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, when i use maximum times?

Comment: Time out error is mostly occurs when there is delay in getting response. Kindly check the end point as well as with different cellular network.

Comment: @Scriptable means some time it works fine

Comment: @ketakiDamale this problem is only on iOS Android app is working fine

Comment: This could be caused by hundreds of different reasons. bad connection, overloaded server/API, bad api programming, poorly optimised network code, too many requests... the list goes on and on. You need to debug the issue further and gather more information. look at charles http proxy to watch the requests being made by your app, see the data size, number of requests, time taken etc

Comment: But this issue only is only happen in when i am connecting to wifi. is it possible bcz with regular network(From sim card) its working fine